# Checking for invalid date in bash script

Tags: bash, date, error-handling

I am checking for a valid date `scrpt.bash test 2019-05-03`

```
date -d $2 2>: 1>:; c=$?
```

If `$c` is 1 then the date is invalid.  If I enter `2019-05-03` I will get a 0 which is correct.  If i enter `2019-05-03u` I get a 0 which is incorrect.  I can enter `2019-05-03uu` then it throws an error.  How can I just check if the date is valid.

Comment: Is the date always provided in this format? 2019-05-03

Comment: Have you try `date -d $2 && c=$?`

Comment: Romeo as he says date is returning sucess (0), even if the date contain a additional character at end. So && will make no difference as it will check the command return too to make a decision.

Comment: _date is valid_ against what criteria? Against what your `date -d` supports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If date is always provided in this format:  '2019-05-03', this will probably work always:

```
#!/bin/sh -

if [ -n "$2" ] && [ "$(date -d "$2" +%Y-%m-%d 2> /dev/null)" = "$2" ]; then
     echo 'This date is valid'
fi
```